# Connect Java code with remote MySQL database by using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, cpanel

I am trying to connect my java code with remote MySQL database by using JDBC but I got this error message on NetBeans JDBC connection window:

> Cannot establish a connection to
>   jdbc:mysql://example.com:3306/databaseName?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
>   using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just making sure, is your JDBC string actually pointing to example.com, and does it really have databaseName? Or is that hiding the true values?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem:

1. Load driver: Class.forName.... - a lot of examples when you google it
2. Check your credentials (url, database name, username, password)

And! It is very important: try to google and you find:

[Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql)

and this:

[com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)